# Firefox .net user authentication not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, firefox, authentication

I want the TaskBar object to be hidden when someone is not logged in

Here's my code:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false){TaskBar.Visible = false;}
```

This works perfectly in IE and Chrome, but for some reason, the TaskBar still shows up in Firefox when no one is logged in. I tried clearing firefox's cache, hoping that that was it, but it wasn't. Is there a more "cross-browser" friendly way of doing this?

[EDIT] The taskbar is a custom user control that I made, and uses no javascript. I just want to set its visibility to false.

[EDIT 2] Here's the code for the taskbar. Its been edited quite a bit for anonymity, so try and keep that in mind. And there are even more user controls attached to it. I'm not going to post the code for those, because I'm not the one who programmed them.

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TaskBar.ascx.cs" Inherits="~.TaskBar" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="act" TagName="CallPopup" Src="~/Call.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="act" TagName="EmailPopup" Src="~/Email.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="act" TagName="NotePopup" Src="~/Note.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="act" TagName="SurveyPopup" Src="~/Survey.ascx" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="act" TagName="TaskPopup" Src="~/Task.ascx" %>

<style type="text/css">

.navBar
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-image: url(~/background.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}

.navBar h2
{
    float: left;
    color: White;
    width: 350px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
}

.links
{
    float: right;
}

.links a
{
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.links img:hover
{
     -moz-opacity:.50; 
     filter:alpha(opacity=50); 
     opacity:.50;
}

</style>

<div class="navBar">
    <h2><asp:Label ID="label" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label></h2>
    <div class="links">
        <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="tasksButton" ImageUrl="~/check.png"  />
        <img src="~/splitter.png" alt="" border="0" />
        <a href="Home" id="homeButton"><img src="~/home.png" alt="" title="Return to the Home Page" border="0" /></a>
        <a href="#" id="callButton"><img src="~/phone.png" alt="" title="Log a Call" border="0" /></a>
        <act:CallPopup ID="pcCall" runat="server" />
        <a href="#" id="emailButton"><img src="~/mail.png" alt="" title="Compose Email" border="0" /></a>
        <act:EmailPopup ID="pcEmail" runat="server" />
        <a href="#" id="noteButton"><img src="~/note.png" alt="" title="Add a Note" border="0" /></a>
        <act:NotePopup ID="pcNote" runat="server" />
        <a href="#" id="newTaskButton"><img src="~/task.png" alt="" title="Add a Task" border="0" /></a>
        <act:TaskPopup ID="pcTask" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

[EDIT 3]

Alright, so here's a bit more on the issue that I just figured out. The way the program is set up is so that users are able to check "Keep Me Logged In", which the program will then do. So I think the issue is actually that Firefox isn't letting the user logout. I have tried clicking our Logout button, and it only doesn't work in Firefox. Maybe that will help push this question forward.

Here's the code for the logout:

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="HeadLoginStatus" runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log Out" LogoutPageUrl="~/Login.aspx" />
```

We're using a basic AnonymousTemplate and LoggedInTemplate system. (I'm not completely sure what all else is needed to describe the login system, sorry...still new at this)

Comment: You code is where? Pre-Render?

Comment: Have you checked the error console to see if you're getting any js errors?

Comment: I'm new at this, so this may be a dumb question, but does the code that I posted use any background js that I wouldn't know about? Otherwise, no, because what I'm doing doesn't involve any javascript.

Comment: Could you post the _code_ of the taskbar?

Comment: I could post the code of the taskbar, but its irrelevant. There is not a _visibility_ property defined on the taskbar, I want to set the asp.net property: visibility = false. Thats it.

Comment: If you would post/link the code for the taskbar we could see why the visibility isn't set the right way. We could also know more about the implementation of the taskbar object. This would help everyone trying to solve your problem :)

Comment: I'll post it then. I hope it helps, but I'm still not convinced that it will.

Comment: Rule of thumb:  you can't provide us too much information.  But it is very easy to provide is too little.

Comment: Is your custom control in an UpdatePanel? or other such thing that could make it render differently?

Comment: Isolating the problem would also be a good start point. In this case you could replace the `UserControl` by a very simple one like a `Label` and see if the problem still remains. If that is the case the problem is most likely that `IsAuthenticated` returns `true`. In that case it might be interesting to know the authentication mode and other data concerning authentication settings.

Comment: @Jan-Peter that's what I'm assuming keeps happening. The question is why it only does that in firefox, but works fine elsewhere. And unfortunately, I'm still new to .net and this project as a whole, so I can only provide so much info.

Comment: @Earlz the custom controls attached to the taskbar? They are DevExpress ASPxPopupControls

Comment: @Inuyasha The only things I've changed are names and file locations, which shouldn't affect how the code is read. Otherwise, I'm not comfortable posting someone else's code without their permission.

Comment: @Jordan, do you understand the point I was making?  And sometimes, names and file locations can be quite relevant.

Comment: When debugging, what values do you see for User?

Comment: Alright, so here's a bit more on the issue that I just figured out. The way the program is set up is so that users are able to check "Keep Me Logged In", which the program will then do. So I think the issue is actually that Firefox isn't letting the user logout. I have tried clicking our Logout button, and it only doesn't work in Firefox. Maybe that will help push this question forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is a Javascript error elsewhere in the page, and its not allowing the user to click the logout button, therefore no cookies are being cleared or postbacks occuring. I'm closing this question, since it's no longer relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Have you used something like Fiddler or Firebug to check whether Firefox is sending the authentication cookie and whether logging out is clearing the cookie correctly?

`HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false` is perfectly valid for checking if the user is authenticated.

Simon

Comment: Yes I have. Since I posted this, I've figured out that whats happening is that the logout link isn't working (doesn't do anything) due to a script issue somewhere else on the page (entirely unrelated). So the link itself actually isn't clearing the cookie at all.